# Multi-configuration job - where is the output?

Tags: jenkins

I'm a newbie to Jenkins, so perhaps it is a stupid question, but...

I'm trying to write a job that will compile my code on several UNIX nodes. I created a multi-configuration project, and add one slave to it.

The job itself is a shell that only does 'ls' and 'pwd'

The output is:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Unix-third-party
Triggering Linux64
Linux64 completed with result SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But I can't see the output of the commends anywhere.

When I changed the matrix to use nodes instead of labels, I managed, to see the output, but I'm still not sure what I did.

A free-style project for the same node works with no problems.

Where do I find the output?

Answer (score 11):

On your job page, you'll see a link called "default" if you have only one node/slave, or the node's name if you have more than one.

Click on that link, then click on a build and console output.

The way it works is:

```
                                         -----------------config 1 -> build #X -> console output
                                       /
Main Job build #X console output ---->
                                       \-----------------config 2 -> build #X -> console output
```

What you are looking at is the console output for the main job, but this only contains trigger information. The actual output is contained in the config 1 and config 2 console outputs.

Comment if you need further clarification, and I'd be glad to help.
Btw, welcome to the world of Jenkins :-)

**==========================================================================**

**EDIT**:

The following URL should take you to yourc console output for a build where you've chosen "Label":

*Substitute everything in <>.*

```
http://<myserver>/job/<jobname>/label=<label>/<buildnumber>/console
```

Comment: Thanks. I do manage to see it with Job->default->Last Build -> Console Output. I'm not sure if it is exactly what you meant.

However, this works only if I configured the job with "Individual Nodes". If I set it with Labels (there is only one machine that fits the label) it doesn't work.

Comment: Default puts me to page Jenkins->jobName->#build->Label. It says "failed to determine (log)". Clicking on 'log' open the console output, and it is empty. I don't see anywhere the name of the machine.

Comment: `Job->default->Last Build -> Console Output` is exactly what I mean. However, you should see the same result whether you select Individual Node or Label. "Failed to determine (Log)" means it could not determine any changes from your version control system system.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/job/Unix-third-party/label=Linux64/20/console gives me 404 error.

Comment: That URL template should have worked for both labels and individual nodes. What version of Jenkins are you using? Can you try `Jenkins ver. 1.486` ? Also, (and this will sound stupid, but still) check that your label is actually Linux64. There is a separate field for labels on the node configuration page, and it need not be the same as the node name.

Comment: Also to note, when you switch from individual node to label, you have to rebuild to get a console. If you built #20 using individual node, you will not have a console for the label, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, however at work, to view our slave consoles, the following URL will work:

https://ci.(company).com/job/QA/job/[projectname]/13/script=loadtest1/console

I'd assume your system would be similar.

Alternatively, if i go to the main ci.(company).com/job/QA/job/[projectname]/
i can see the recent job on the left corner.

When selected that specific job, at the base of the screen is our configurations, which you select, then can view the console output of that specific job.

Viewing the main jenkins job will not output console logs from slaves.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, not sure what caused it, but I was able to get my build configs to show console logs and artifacts once more by deleting "builds" and "configurations" folders under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\ProjectName".

Obviously, this also gets rid of your build history, but I just need the configs running again.